# Error when validating the deployment 'We couldn't retrieve the design time component information for component'

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, sfdx-error, deployment-error, github-actions

I am trying to validate Salesforce metadata deployment and getting the following error.
Github actions trigger the deployment validation when a PR is raised.
We couldn't retrieve the design time component information for component c:cfUS_ViewESIIDAndSA.
I have verified the SFDX CLI ver being used is the latest.

What do I or the dev needs to do to fix this?

[image: Error details]